# Text binarization

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I'd like to binarize this image:
[image: http://imgur.com/A5u9xSA]

to use it with tesseract-ocr. Currently, I managed to get this:
[image: http://imgur.com/bU0FSt8]

But I need clear image with only text, without black background parts, like this one:
[image: imgur.com/KXQNErM]

My current code:

```
img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
filtered = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 405, 1)
bitnot = cv2.bitwise_not(filtered)
cv2.imshow('image', bitnot)
cv2.imwrite("h2kcw2/out1.png", bitnot)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do two thresholds, one to get the characters and one to get the background, then combine them. If I was more familiar with opencv I'd give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however it didn't help me, or I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Are you meaning to not use the `GaussianBlur` results in anything?  You're doing `adaptiveThreashold` on the original `img`, not on the blurred `blur`.

Comment: You can use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` to get the inverse result of your threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular threshold can present a good result:

[image: Result]

```
img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('image', thresh)
cv2.imwrite("h2kcw2/out1.png", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: +1 Save it as tiff and pass it to Tesseract via cmd line. Let us know how the detection went.

Comment: Works great! Sorry for late answer, but I had no access to computer for few days. Thanks!