# Cannot read text from screenshot due to background color using PyTesseract

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract and detect text from computer / mobile screenshots using pytesseract.
It works fine but in some cases like this, button text is not detected may be due to green background.

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Image After Text Detection

[image: Detected Text]

Here is the code I am using:

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)# img is an numpy nd array, i.e image read using OpenCV
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    # eliminating blank characters
    if d['text'][i].strip() == '': continue
    else: print(d['text'][i])
    (x,y,w,h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

plot_image(img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binarizing the image such that it becomes black and white. Binarization/Image Thresholding is a commonly used image processing method for such use cases.

These links might help.

1.[ImageThresholding-Opencv](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)

2.[Adaptive Thresholding](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_threshold_adaptive.html)

3.[Text Binarization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185550/text-binarization)

Comment: That worked in terms of text detection.
Here is the output image link.
https://ibb.co/qJCX5Gb
But **detected text is incorrect**:
Instead of **create account** it returns **COXEIND**

Comment: That depends on pytesseract only. Try tuning the parameters or look for other OCR models. If your use case is unique, train your own model to suit your conditions.

Comment: OKay understood!!
One more thing. This is the output of Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding.
https://ibb.co/gmcmr9T
How can I make text more clear from the same?

Comment: Try decreasing blocksize. Play around with parameters for your usecase.This link (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_adaptive_threshold.htm) might help.